# Is there /etc/shadows in android termux?

Tags: termux

I tried the following:

```
$ pwd
/system/etc
$ ls | grep 'shadow'
```

But nothing was found.

Comment: What is the actual problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: [Learn how to ask](https://android.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 2):

### No. There isn't

Keep in mind that Termux is only a Linux **environment**. It's at least vastly different from a real GNU/Linux system.

Android has its own Unix user system, which does not have logins and passwords. So you'd not expect `/etc/passwd` and `/etc/shadows` to exist.